# AngularFire2 4.0 does not handle Firestore DB rule insufficient permissions error

Tags: angularjs, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, firebase-security

I am working with firestore db rules, here are the rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /tours/{tourId}{
  allow read: if resource.data.title == 'My Tour';
  allow write: if true
 }}}
```

So it should only allow tour that has title value = 'My Tour', and it does it. But the problem is when I am trying to get the collection of tours by [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md) it gave me "ERROR Error: Missing or insufficient permissions", basically it should skip all the records or at least it should handle the error, but it does not any idea how to make it working ?(I don't want to change my rule condition :) )

Here is angular code:

af.collection(`/tours`).snapshotChanges()

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Security rules do not filter results for you. If your query is too broad, it will fail against the rules. Your query should include a `where` clause matching your rules. In this case:

```
af.collection('tours').where('title', '==', 'My Tour')
```

Comment: Thanks, I have made the client side query as:                         
      af.collection<any>(`tours`, ref =>
      ref.where('startDate', '<', new Date())                                                                      and my db rules:                                                                                                                              
    match /tours/{tourId}{
     allow read:  if (resource.data.startDate < request.time.date());
     allow write: if isAdmin();
   }   but I am getting permission error.

Comment: startDate is saved as timestamp filed in firestore, I have attached the screenshot to my question.